# True or False - Taylor expansions

Tags: calculus

> **True or false:** If $f$ is a Taylor expansion about $x_{0} = 0$ with radius $R$, then $$g(x) = f\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)$$ has a Taylor expansion about $x_{0} = 1$ with radius $2R$

I think this is true because for every $f$ that I choose I get an answer that satisfies the claim... I don't know how to continue from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on [Martin's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1831296/327486): $$\left| \frac{x-1}{2} \right| <R \iff |x-1| < 2R$$

The set of $x$ satisfying this condition is equal to all points within a distance $2R$ of $x_0=1$.

Therefore, since the Taylor expansion of $g$ exists if and only if the Taylor expansion of $f\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)$ exists, which occurs if and only if the above condition holds, we get that the Taylor expansion of $g$ exists/is valid for all $x$ within a distance $2R$ of $x_0=1$, since that is equivalent to the above given condition.

This is what meant by thinking of $\frac{x-1}{2}$ as a new variable: if we define $$y:=\frac{x-1}{2}$$ then $$|y|<R \iff |x-1|<2R$$ and the Taylor expansion of $g(x)$ exists if and only if the Taylor expansion of $f(y)$ exists because, by definition, $g=f(y)$. I hope this makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac{x-1}2\right| < R\iff\cdots$$

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: @Amir, think in $(x-1)/2$ as another variable.